# ColorBox jQuery Help Request

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox, colorbox

I have no idea how to manipulate jQuery, so I'm turning to stackoverflow once again in hopes of a quick solution!

I'm using a jQuery script called ColorBox for a lightbox effect. I cannot find out how to edit this script to include the Facebook comments script.

This is the jQuery file contents:

```
(function(a,b,c){function Z(c,d,e){var g=b.createElement(c);return d&&(g.id=f+d),e&&(g.style.cssText=e),a(g)}function $(a){var b=y.length,c=(Q+a)%b;return c<0?b+c:c}function _(a,b){return Math.round((/%/.test(a)?(b==="x"?z.width():z.height())/100:1)*parseInt(a,10))}function ba(a){return K.photo||/\.(gif|png|jpe?g|bmp|ico)((#|\?).*)?$/i.test(a)}function bb(){var b;K=a.extend({},a.data(P,e));for(b in K)a.isFunction(K[b])&&b.slice(0,2)!=="on"&&(K[b]=K[b].call(P));K.rel=K.rel||P.rel||"nofollow",K.href=K.href||a(P).attr("href"),K.title=K.title||P.title,typeof K.href=="string"&&(K.href=a.trim(K.href))}function bc(b,c){a.event.trigger(b),c&&c.call(P)}function bd(){var a,b=f+"Slideshow_",c="click."+f,d,e,g;K.slideshow&&y[1]?(d=function(){F.text(K.slideshowStop).unbind(c).bind(j,function(){if(K.loop||y[Q+1])a=setTimeout(W.next,K.slideshowSpeed)}).bind(i,function(){clearTimeout(a)}).one(c+" "+k,e),r.removeClass(b+"off").addClass(b+"on"),a=setTimeout(W.next,K.slideshowSpeed)},e=function(){clearTimeout(a),F.text(K.slideshowStart).unbind([j,i,k,c].join(" ")).one(c,function(){W.next(),d()}),r.removeClass(b+"on").addClass(b+"off")},K.slideshowAuto?d():e()):r.removeClass(b+"off "+b+"on")}function be(b){U||(P=b,bb(),y=a(P),Q=0,K.rel!=="nofollow"&&(y=a("."+g).filter(function(){var b=a.data(this,e).rel||this.rel;return b===K.rel}),Q=y.index(P),Q===-1&&(y=y.add(P),Q=y.length-1)),S||(S=T=!0,r.show(),K.returnFocus&&a(P).blur().one(l,function(){a(this).focus()}),q.css({opacity:+K.opacity,cursor:K.overlayClose?"pointer":"auto"}).show(),K.w=_(K.initialWidth,"x"),K.h=_(K.initialHeight,"y"),W.position(),o&&z.bind("resize."+p+" scroll."+p,function(){q.css({width:z.width(),height:z.height(),top:z.scrollTop(),left:z.scrollLeft()})}).trigger("resize."+p),bc(h,K.onOpen),J.add(D).hide(),I.html(K.close).show()),W.load(!0))}function bf(){!r&&b.body&&(Y=!1,z=a(c),r=Z(X).attr({id:e,"class":n?f+(o?"IE6":"IE"):""}).hide(),q=Z(X,"Overlay",o?"position:absolute":"").hide(),s=Z(X,"Wrapper"),t=Z(X,"Content").append(A=Z(X,"LoadedContent","width:0; height:0; overflow:hidden"),C=Z(X,"LoadingOverlay").add(Z(X,"LoadingGraphic")),D=Z(X,"Title"),E=Z(X,"Current"),G=Z(X,"Next"),H=Z(X,"Previous"),F=Z(X,"Slideshow").bind(h,bd),I=Z(X,"Close")),s.append(Z(X).append(Z(X,"TopLeft"),u=Z(X,"TopCenter"),Z(X,"TopRight")),Z(X,!1,"clear:left").append(v=Z(X,"MiddleLeft"),t,w=Z(X,"MiddleRight")),Z(X,!1,"clear:left").append(Z(X,"BottomLeft"),x=Z(X,"BottomCenter"),Z(X,"BottomRight"))).find("div div").css({"float":"left"}),B=Z(X,!1,"position:absolute; width:9999px; visibility:hidden; display:none"),J=G.add(H).add(E).add(F),a(b.body).append(q,r.append(s,B)))}function bg(){return r?(Y||(Y=!0,L=u.height()+x.height()+t.outerHeight(!0)-t.height(),M=v.width()+w.width()+t.outerWidth(!0)-t.width(),N=A.outerHeight(!0),O=A.outerWidth(!0),r.css({"padding-bottom":L,"padding-right":M}),G.click(function(){W.next()}),H.click(function(){W.prev()}),I.click(function(){W.close()}),q.click(function(){K.overlayClose&&W.close()}),a(b).bind("keydown."+f,function(a){var b=a.keyCode;S&&K.escKey&&b===27&&(a.preventDefault(),W.close()),S&&K.arrowKey&&y[1]&&(b===37?(a.preventDefault(),H.click()):b===39&&(a.preventDefault(),G.click()))}),a("."+g,b).live("click",function(a){a.which>1||a.shiftKey||a.altKey||a.metaKey||(a.preventDefault(),be(this))})),!0):!1}var d={transition:"elastic",speed:300,width:!1,initialWidth:"600",innerWidth:!1,maxWidth:!1,height:!1,initialHeight:"450",innerHeight:!1,maxHeight:!1,scalePhotos:!0,scrolling:!0,inline:!1,html:!1,iframe:!1,fastIframe:!0,photo:!1,href:!1,title:!1,rel:!1,opacity:.9,preloading:!0,current:"image {current} of {total}",previous:"previous",next:"next",close:"close",open:!1,returnFocus:!0,reposition:!0,loop:!0,slideshow:!1,slideshowAuto:!0,slideshowSpeed:2500,slideshowStart:"start slideshow",slideshowStop:"stop slideshow",onOpen:!1,onLoad:!1,onComplete:!1,onCleanup:!1,onClosed:!1,overlayClose:!0,escKey:!0,arrowKey:!0,top:!1,bottom:!1,left:!1,right:!1,fixed:!1,data:undefined},e="colorbox",f="cbox",g=f+"Element",h=f+"_open",i=f+"_load",j=f+"_complete",k=f+"_cleanup",l=f+"_closed",m=f+"_purge",n=!a.support.opacity&&!a.support.style,o=n&&!c.XMLHttpRequest,p=f+"_IE6",q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z,A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X="div",Y;if(a.colorbox)return;a(bf),W=a.fn[e]=a[e]=function(b,c){var f=this;b=b||{},bf();if(bg()){if(!f[0]){if(f.selector)return f;f=a("<a/>"),b.open=!0}c&&(b.onComplete=c),f.each(function(){a.data(this,e,a.extend({},a.data(this,e)||d,b))}).addClass(g),(a.isFunction(b.open)&&b.open.call(f)||b.open)&&be(f[0])}return f},W.position=function(a,b){function i(a){u[0].style.width=x[0].style.width=t[0].style.width=a.style.width,t[0].style.height=v[0].style.height=w[0].style.height=a.style.height}var c=0,d=0,e=r.offset(),g=z.scrollTop(),h=z.scrollLeft();z.unbind("resize."+f),r.css({top:-9e4,left:-9e4}),K.fixed&&!o?(e.top-=g,e.left-=h,r.css({position:"fixed"})):(c=g,d=h,r.css({position:"absolute"})),K.right!==!1?d+=Math.max(z.width()-K.w-O-M-_(K.right,"x"),0):K.left!==!1?d+=_(K.left,"x"):d+=Math.round(Math.max(z.width()-K.w-O-M,0)/2),K.bottom!==!1?c+=Math.max(z.height()-K.h-N-L-_(K.bottom,"y"),0):K.top!==!1?c+=_(K.top,"y"):c+=Math.round(Math.max(z.height()-K.h-N-L,0)/2),r.css({top:e.top,left:e.left}),a=r.width()===K.w+O&&r.height()===K.h+N?0:a||0,s[0].style.width=s[0].style.height="9999px",r.dequeue().animate({width:K.w+O,height:K.h+N,top:c,left:d},{duration:a,complete:function(){i(this),T=!1,s[0].style.width=K.w+O+M+"px",s[0].style.height=K.h+N+L+"px",K.reposition&&setTimeout(function(){z.bind("resize."+f,W.position)},1),b&&b()},step:function(){i(this)}})},W.resize=function(a){S&&(a=a||{},a.width&&(K.w=_(a.width,"x")-O-M),a.innerWidth&&(K.w=_(a.innerWidth,"x")),A.css({width:K.w}),a.height&&(K.h=_(a.height,"y")-N-L),a.innerHeight&&(K.h=_(a.innerHeight,"y")),!a.innerHeight&&!a.height&&(A.css({height:"auto"}),K.h=A.height()),A.css({height:K.h}),W.position(K.transition==="none"?0:K.speed))},W.prep=function(b){function g(){return K.w=K.w||A.width(),K.w=K.mw&&K.mw<K.w?K.mw:K.w,K.w}function h(){return K.h=K.h||A.height(),K.h=K.mh&&K.mh<K.h?K.mh:K.h,K.h}if(!S)return;var c,d=K.transition==="none"?0:K.speed;A.remove(),A=Z(X,"LoadedContent").append(b),A.hide().appendTo(B.show()).css({width:g(),overflow:K.scrolling?"auto":"hidden"}).css({height:h()}).prependTo(t),B.hide(),a(R).css({"float":"none"}),o&&a("select").not(r.find("select")).filter(function(){return this.style.visibility!=="hidden"}).css({visibility:"hidden"}).one(k,function(){this.style.visibility="inherit"}),c=function(){function q(){n&&r[0].style.removeAttribute("filter")}var b,c,g=y.length,h,i="frameBorder",k="allowTransparency",l,o,p;if(!S)return;l=function(){clearTimeout(V),C.hide(),bc(j,K.onComplete)},n&&R&&A.fadeIn(100),D.html(K.title).add(A).show();if(g>1){typeof K.current=="string"&&E.html(K.current.replace("{current}",Q+1).replace("{total}",g)).show(),G[K.loop||Q<g-1?"show":"hide"]().html(K.next),H[K.loop||Q?"show":"hide"]().html(K.previous),K.slideshow&&F.show();if(K.preloading){b=[$(-1),$(1)];while(c=y[b.pop()])o=a.data(c,e).href||c.href,a.isFunction(o)&&(o=o.call(c)),ba(o)&&(p=new Image,p.src=o)}}else J.hide();K.iframe?(h=Z("iframe")[0],i in h&&(h[i]=0),k in h&&(h[k]="true"),h.name=f+ +(new Date),K.fastIframe?l():a(h).one("load",l),h.src=K.href,K.scrolling||(h.scrolling="no"),a(h).addClass(f+"Iframe").appendTo(A).one(m,function(){h.src="//about:blank"})):l(),K.transition==="fade"?r.fadeTo(d,1,q):q()},K.transition==="fade"?r.fadeTo(d,0,function(){W.position(0,c)}):W.position(d,c)},W.load=function(b){var c,d,e=W.prep;T=!0,R=!1,P=y[Q],b||bb(),bc(m),bc(i,K.onLoad),K.h=K.height?_(K.height,"y")-N-L:K.innerHeight&&_(K.innerHeight,"y"),K.w=K.width?_(K.width,"x")-O-M:K.innerWidth&&_(K.innerWidth,"x"),K.mw=K.w,K.mh=K.h,K.maxWidth&&(K.mw=_(K.maxWidth,"x")-O-M,K.mw=K.w&&K.w<K.mw?K.w:K.mw),K.maxHeight&&(K.mh=_(K.maxHeight,"y")-N-L,K.mh=K.h&&K.h<K.mh?K.h:K.mh),c=K.href,V=setTimeout(function(){C.show()},100),K.inline?(Z(X).hide().insertBefore(a(c)[0]).one(m,function(){a(this).replaceWith(A.children())}),e(a(c))):K.iframe?e(" "):K.html?e(K.html):ba(c)?(a(R=new Image).addClass(f+"Photo").error(function(){K.title=!1,e(Z(X,"Error").text("This image could not be loaded"))}).load(function(){var a;R.onload=null,K.scalePhotos&&(d=function(){R.height-=R.height*a,R.width-=R.width*a},K.mw&&R.width>K.mw&&(a=(R.width-K.mw)/R.width,d()),K.mh&&R.height>K.mh&&(a=(R.height-K.mh)/R.height,d())),K.h&&(R.style.marginTop=Math.max(K.h-R.height,0)/2+"px"),y[1]&&(K.loop||y[Q+1])&&(R.style.cursor="pointer",R.onclick=function(){W.next()}),n&&(R.style.msInterpolationMode="bicubic"),setTimeout(function(){e(R)},1)}),setTimeout(function(){R.src=c},1)):c&&B.load(c,K.data,function(b,c,d){e(c==="error"?Z(X,"Error").text("Request unsuccessful: "+d.statusText):a(this).contents())})},W.next=function(){!T&&y[1]&&(K.loop||y[Q+1])&&(Q=$(1),W.load())},W.prev=function(){!T&&y[1]&&(K.loop||Q)&&(Q=$(-1),W.load())},W.close=function(){S&&!U&&(U=!0,S=!1,bc(k,K.onCleanup),z.unbind("."+f+" ."+p),q.fadeTo(200,0),r.stop().fadeTo(300,0,function(){r.add(q).css({opacity:1,cursor:"auto"}).hide(),bc(m),A.remove(),setTimeout(function(){U=!1,bc(l,K.onClosed)},1)}))},W.remove=function(){a([]).add(r).add(q).remove(),r=null,a("."+g).removeData(e).removeClass(g).die()},W.element=function(){return a(P)},W.settings=d})(jQuery,document,this);
```

And the code for Facebook comments is simple!

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script>
<fb:comments href="YOUR_CANONICAL_URL"></fb:comments>
```

Does anyone have any idea how to smash the second bit in to the first to make ColorBox output the image as well as the selected Facebook comments?

Thanks in advance,
Kamron

Answer (score 1):

First of all, that's [minified](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minification_%28programming%29) JavaScript, so editing that particular script will be difficult. I'd suggest getting the source if you really want to make modifications to it.

> I have no idea how to manipulate jQuery

Plugin development requires intermediate to advanced knowledge of jQuery and JavaScript. Modifying someone else's plugin means that "you own it", i.e. no one else has the same code as you do and you are responsible for it. You can't take updates to the code, nor can you expect anyone else to know about your changes.

With that in mind, perhaps you can use the [public API](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox) and attach to an event and/or manipulate the content?

I am not familiar with Colorbox, but I noted that it offers several events and callback options, as well as `$.colorbox.element()` which might let you manipulate the content. For example, when the box opens, a callback could be fired during which you could retrieve Facebook content and insert it into the box.

Comment: This is exactly why I love stackoverflow! Thanks for your help. I'll keep trucking and see if I can get it figured out.

Answer (score 1):

Agree with @Tim Medora 1000% but also have this to offer based on my speculation about your desire, as I am familiar with the ColorBox plugin.

Recommend you explore ColorBox's out-of-the-box ability to open HTML content in its UI (as opposed to only images). In this way, you'll have a starting point into which to inject the comments from the social network stream.

Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

You have couple of choices.

Get the fb stuff working in a div somewhere on your page first. Then look at examples on how how to display that div in colorbox. That's very straightforward. When you have that working wrap your div with fg guts and hide it so it becomes visible only when colorbox gets triggered.

... or, put fb stuff on bare page and load that page into an iframe. Colorbox makes that simple as well.

So far there appears no reason to mess with colorbox itself.